# How to set offset for python cartopy geometry?

Tags: python, cartopy

So the problem is that when I add a geometry from .shp file to the cartopy figure, there is an offset and I have no idea how to set the offset.

[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrdaP.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
#from cartopy.feature import GSHHSFeature 

from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader


canada_east = -63
canada_west = -123
canada_north = 75
canada_south = 37

standard_parallels = (49, 77)
central_longitude = -(91 + 52 / 60)

data = Reader('icitw_wgs84')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,
                     projection=ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=central_longitude,
                                                      standard_parallels=standard_parallels))
ax.set_extent([-79.65, -79.1, 43.57, 43.87])


ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES.with_scale('10m'))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND.with_scale('10m'))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS.with_scale('10m'))


ax.add_geometries(data.geometries(), crs=ccrs.Geodetic(), edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is due to the low resolution land/lake data set. For maps of this scale you are probably better off using map tiles instead of the NaturalEarth land feature. There are several choices already available in cartopy, Stamen Terrain or Open Street Map might be good choices:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import StamenTerrain, OSM

standard_parallels = (49, 77)
central_longitude = -(91 + 52 / 60)

data = Reader('citygcs')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,                  
                     projection=ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=central_longitude,                                     
                                                      standard_parallels=standard_parallels))
ax.set_extent([-79.65, -79.1, 43.57, 43.87])

tiler = OSM()
ax.add_image(tiler, 10)

ax.add_geometries(data.geometries(), crs=ccrs.Geodetic(), edgecolor='k', 
facecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

[image: Totornto OSM]

Or using `StamenTerrain`:

[image: Toronto Stamen]

There may be further issues regarding referencing ellipse (I notice WGS84 in the shapefile name), there is a good reference here: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.16/gallery/effects_of_the_ellipse.html.

Comment: Also, do you know how to change the tile of OSM? I looked around but did not really understand what's going on. So I have to use something like : url (optional) – URL pointing to a tile source and containing {x}, {y}, and {z}. Such as: (‘https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/’ ‘World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg’)   but should I implement it?